# How does the internally parsing of numbers and especially decimal numbers work?

Tags: parsing, numbers

How does the internally parsing of strings into number formats work? I have imagined something like this. Does that match to the actual implementation?

(not related to any particular programming language)

```
int getDigit(char c)
{
    if (c == '0')
        return 0;
    if (c == '1')
       return 1;
    if (c == '2')
       return 2;
    // ...
}

int parseInt(string str)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlength(str); i++)
        result = result * 10 + getDigit(str[i]);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of getting each digit value first, then multiplying by 10 as fit, is a common implementation. For instance, [this one from MS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/atoi.c.htm), is basically the same as your implementation.

In most languages you can get the integer value by subtracting the character `'0'` from the input character, because the way the text encoding works.